# Difference between httpd_sys_content_t httpd_user_content_t

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, selinux

What is the difference between the selinux types **httpd_sys_content_t** and **httpd_user_content_t**? Looking e.g. [here](https://linux.die.net/man/8/httpd_selinux) I can't find much in the way of specifics.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/701051/126632

Comment: ok, that's sort of helpful for **httpd_user_content_t** but doesn't mention **httpd_sys_content_t** or really answer my question at all, which is 'what is the difference between them?'

Answer (score 1):

`httpd_sys_content_t` type is default for `/var/www/html`

and if you wish to put your website in your home directory, you can change your file and directory to the type of `httpd_sys_content_t` for the `httpd` works.

But it is not recommended, the best way is to change them to the type of `httpd_user_content_t`. And then set SELinux boolean value with:

```
 setsebool httpd_enable_homedirs on
```

So that, the type `httpd_user_content_t` can work fine in your home directory.